# Magento 2.2.6: What is block delimiter?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

After I upgraded Magento to 2.2.6, if I go to my account, this shows me the nodes with this class:

```
<span class="delimiter"></span>
```

This makes it look really bad:

[image]

**Inspector:**

[image]

This comes from:

> Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Delimiter

```
<?php  

namespace Magento\Customer\Block\Account;

/**
 * Class for delimiter.
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.2.0
 */
class Delimiter extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements SortLinkInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @since 100.2.0
     */
    public function getSortOrder()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::SORT_ORDER);
    }
}
```

And the phtml is:

> magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\account\navigation-delimiter.phtml

```
<li class="nav item">
    <span class="delimiter"></span>
</li>
```

My solution is to overwrite, but I do not know if it is the correct solution.

Comment: yes, correct solution, I found same in old 2.2.1